# Display contents of the database table selected by user in Django

Tags: django, database, django-models, django-views, model

As per user selection I want to display course details. I do not want to create multiple pages for each course detail.
So, at `course-detail.html` I am passing a `course-code` as hidden value in html form which is table name in my database project.
When a user submits the query for course, I pass the course-code value by `POST` method into my `views.py` file.
But there I am not able to use post method string as a model name.

`courses.html`

```
{% for courses in english_courses %}
<form action="{% url "course-detail" %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="course-code" value="{{courses.course_code}}">
  <button class="btn-lg btn-primary d-inline-flex align-items-center" type="submit" onclick="document.location.href='{% url "course-detail" %}';">
    {{course.name}}
  </button>
  &nbsp;
  {% endfor %}</form>
```

`views.py`

```
def course_detail(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        course_request = request.POST['course-code']
        course_request = course_request.capitalize()
        course_details = course_request.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'course-detail.html', {'course': course_details})  
    else:
        messages.warning(request, "Link seems to be broken. Please contact admin.")
        return render(request, 'course-detail.html')
```

this throws an error:

```
AttributeError at /english/course-detail
'str' object has no attribute 'objects'
```

Comment: I guess you're trying to get Course object in 5th row of ´views.py´ You can do it by ´course_details = Course.objects.get(id=course_request)´

Answer (score 0):

First, you must receive the course name or course ID from the user with a POST request and display the content details by filtering that ID.

```
from .model import course <- # New

def course_detail(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        course_request = request.POST['course-code']
        course_request = course_request.capitalize()
        course_details = course.objects.filter(course-code=course_request) <- # New
        return render(request, 'course-detail.html', {'course': course_details})  
    else:
        messages.warning(request, "Link seems to be broken. Please contact admin.")
        return render(request, 'course-detail.html')
```

Comment: course.objects.filter(course-code=course_request) couldn't be correct because field name cannot include hypen "-"

Comment: Yes, I know, I just wrote an example for you, which should be like this, and you should look at your model and filter and display the courses according to the model you made.
I don't know the name of your model and for example I wrote course and imported it.